# Fetch POJOs grouped by an external field in JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

Take the usual example of the `book` and `author` tables in a many-to-many (`book_author`) relationship.

I currently have this and it works:

```
Map<UUID, List<Book>> booksByAuthorId = dsl
    .select(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID, BOOK_AUTHOR.book())
    .from(BOOK_AUTHOR)
    .where(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID.in(authorIds))
    .fetchGroups(
        BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID,
        mapping((a, bookRecord) -> mapping(Book::new).apply(bookRecord)));
```

but the nested `mapping` makes me feel I'm doing something wrong. Is that really the most obvious approach?

Comment: *"but surely there is a better way to express this, right?"* This is a very subjective question without a clear goal, so I doubt it's possible to answer this. *"Also, can this be expressed as a multiset query"* of course it can. *"I know it would most likely be an overkill here"* no, why would it be? *"but I'm still curious how that would look like, because I could not get it right."* what have you tried? Why did it fail?

Comment: 1. I'll rephrase it then: is the nested `mapping` the obvious way to handle this? 2. Can be expressed just as concisely with simpler constructs (as I have already done). 3. I'll update the question with an example of what I tried, but I could not figure out how to express it, the generics just never lined up.

Comment: OK I think I get it now. I mean, `mapping()` is just a convenience utility to turn a `Record[N]` type into a `Function[N]` higher order function in a type safe way. it was introduced to make type safe `Book::new` constructor reference expressions available. But it isn't strictly necessary, there are many ways to do the same thing. I'm still not clear what would constitute "better" (which is very subjective), so I still think this is a hard to answer question, but I can try? If my answer isn't "better", then maybe a clear specification of what constitutes "good" and "bad" for you could help.

Comment: Regarding the `MULTISET` part, I'm happy to answer a new question about this, if you can show what you tried, so I can explain why that might not have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, probably?

```java
.fetchGroups(
    BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID,
    r -> r.value2().into(Book.class)
);
```

Or this:

```java
.fetchGroups(
    r -> r.value1(),
    r -> r.value2().into(Book.class)
);
```

This uses reflection (in the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html)) to map the book columns of the nested `BOOK_AUTHOR.book()` record into the `Book` POJO. If you enabled the `<recordsImplementingRecordN/>` flag in your code generator, you could do this, in the query:

```java
BOOK_AUTHOR.book().mapping(Book::new)
```

There are maybe other ways to "improve" things, though as I said in the comments, this appears to be subjective. Or maybe, you're looking for a *specific* operator that could be added to the jOOQ API? [You could request it here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this is what I was trying to make it look like, and for some reason kept missing. It was the middle of the night, after all  I rewrote the question to clarify what I meant with `multiset`, but your answer already covers that too, so it's all good :)

Comment: @kaqqao: Would you mind asking the `multiset` part of your question in a new question? I'd love to answer it, but it doesn't seem to be strictly related to your original question. Yet, it's a question that I think will be useful for others, nonetheless. It is more about correlating `multiset` subqueries, for which there will be a great solution in jOOQ 3.19. The 3.18 solution might indeed seem a bit laborious.

Comment: Sure thing. I removed the multiset part from this question and moved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76371252/fetch-grouped-pojos-using-multiset-in-jooq